# Espresso Testing throws PerformException

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm doing espresso test for an App that launches the `SplashActivity` and then the `LoginActivity`.

When test start I register the `IdlingResource` and immediately `setIdleState` to `false` on the `setUp` test method. By that time, `LoginActivity` is being launched. On the method  `onWindowFocusChanged` when the activity has focus I call `setIdleState true`.

```
@Rule public ActivityTestRule<SplashActivity> mActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(SplashActivity.class);

private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    mIdlingResource = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getIdlingResource();
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    ApplicationContext.getInstance().getIdlingResource().setIdleState(false);
}
```

During the test I peform these actions

```
onView(withId(R.id.edit_email)).perform(clearText()).
                        perform(typeText("user@mail.com"), pressImeActionButton());

onView(withId(R.id.edit_password)).perform(clearText()).
                        perform(typeText("password"), closeSoftKeyboard()); //<--- This is where the PerformanceException is thrown.

onView(withId(R.id.login_button)).perform(click());
```

I tried to delay the `setIdleState(true)` by calling it inside a `Thread`.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        IdlingResource idlingResource = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getIdlingResource();

        if(hasFocus)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(idlingResource != null)
                       idlingResource.setIdleState(true);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

I did this in order to continue the test once the `LoginActivity` is fully displayed. But it didn't work either.

The exception message that I got is

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is displayed on the screen to the user and is assignable from class: class android.widget.EditText)
Target view: "AppCompatEditText{id=2131296987, res-name=some_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1212, height=0, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@b49a60f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x81 imeOptions=0x4000006 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=Password label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null ], x=0.0, y=181.0, text=1234, hint=Password, input-type=129, ime-target=true, has-links=false}"
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:238)
```

**How can I fix this PerformanceException?**

This test is based on according to the Espresso Recorder but I got a lot of `Thread.sleep`. Espresso Recorder also recommends to user `IdlingResource` to avoid those sleeps.

Comment: In unit test you test a unit independently.  A good way to test your case would be to have 2 differently test classes that test their own Activity. One to test `SplashActivity` it would just test if views are visible inside the Activity and current activity is changed to `LoginActivity` after X seconds. Then a separate test class will test `LoginActivity` independently.

Comment: I was going that route, test each activity as a one, but `SplashActivity` has some setup that `LoginActivity` needs and `LoginActivity` has some setups that the `MainActivity` needs. `MainActivity` is where I need to do the testing.

Comment: Still, test each Activity separately, use mock objects to provide setups data before starting test.